# Getting error after load schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am load schema and access the newly created module and showing the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin/slidersimages#index
```

Showing

```
/var/www/musicradio/trunk/app/views/admin/slidersimages/index.html.erb where line #30 raised:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "slidersimages" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"slidersimages"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"slidersimages"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: Have you created a migration for this? the error is indicating that there is no slidersimages table.

Comment: It has a table in a database already

Comment: can you show the code in `app/views/admin/slidersimages/index.html.erb` and your schema.rb? Also, what does the database look like? I'm guessing the DB table may be more like sliders_images vs sliders images.